# python lxml parse url with binding a different interface

Tags: python, lxml

i need to bind a different ip (already assigned at my second interface) when i use lxml for parse the result of an url :

```
from lxml.html import parse
doc = parse("http://www.google.com").getroot()
```

Are there any way to manually pass the interface to lxml ?
For example :

```
doc = parse(url="http://www.google.com",interface="192.168.0.154").getroot()
```

Somebody have any idea ? how can i do this ?
Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. How does binding an ip work into your lxml issue?

Comment: i have another interface with another plan dedicated to this kind of work, so i need to use the secondary interface to do that.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is nothing in lxml directly but it would be easy enough pass the source to lxml using other methods that allow you to specify the interface